# ''In'' before '' Last ''

Tags: prepositions

I had mugged up a rule that we should not use prepositions like '' in '', '' on '' and at before some words like '' Last'', '' every'', this and so on, but I found a sentence recently;
1) Do you know how Indian Media have curbed ''in'' the last five years.

Should we use '' in'' here? If so, what is the exception ?
let me know pls.
thank you in advance!

Comment: Do we know how India Media curbed ***what*** in the last five years? With the sentence structure as it is, that's the transitive use of the verb *curb*. (*She curbed her curiosity.* *Curb your enthusiasm.*) But the object of the verb is missing.

Comment: As for the question itself, *I travelled to Paris three times* ***in*** *the last five years*. It's grammatical and natural to use *in* with such a construction.

Answer (score 1):

> - In every case of a rule of English grammar, one can find an exception.
> - She was on her last legs.
> - On every well-set table there will be a napkin.
> - At last, I have found the correct rule.

In short, I don't think the suggested rule is in fact a rule.

> Do you know how Indian Media have curbed in the last five years.

Does sound a bit odd, I would have written

> > Do you know how the Indian media have been curbed in the last five years.

But perhaps there is a usage of "curbed" in Indian English different from the usage in US English.